Sum Distribution of Subset of Persons in Independent Dirichlet-Multinomial Models
I am working with a scenario involving multiple entities, say $d$ different persons, each of whom has data across $L$ categories. The model is structured as follows:

Each category’s counts are sampled independently for each person using a Dirichlet-multinomial distribution.
The number of samples in each category is $N$, and the Dirichlet prior for all categories has the same parameter vector $ \alpha$ of dimension $d$. The counts for each category are generated independently.
Each person’s overall distribution is the product of these independent Dirichlet-multinomial distributions across the categories.

Given this setup, I have two questions:

Sum Distribution Across a Subset of Persons: If I take a subset of these $d$ persons and sum their counts for each category, what is the resulting distribution? How can I mathematically describe this sum distribution? Can I make a statement about the entropy of the sum?

Probability of Low Counts in One Category vs. High Counts in Another: Given that each person’s category counts are sampled independently according to a Dirichlet-multinomial distribution, is there a way to quantify the probability that, within a particular person, one category has a low count while another category has a high count? Is there closed form solution for this?


Any insights, mathematical formulations, or references that could help address these questions would be greatly appreciated.
